# How much time between mocha retries

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

in a simple test like this

```
  it ('sample test', function(done) {      
      this.retries(2);
      expect(1).to.equal(2);
      done();
  });
```

how much time is there between the retries? And is there a way to make an exponential backoff using mocha?